# RequestFactory receive data

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I am trying to take data back using GWT RF, I am having some troubles though.
Here is my factory,proxy and entities.

Entity under server.domain package:

```
public class Job implements Serializable {
private int id;
private String announcer;
private String applied;
private String date;
private String description;
private String email;
private String title;
private int version;
static SessionFactory factory;
static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
public Job() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
        configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
//Setters&Getters
public void persist() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Job job = this;
            session.save(job);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
public static List<Job> findAllJobs() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Job> list = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("select * from Job");
            list = query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The JobRequest class file contains:

```
Request<List<JobProxy>> findAllJobs();
```

And entry module:

```
final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
JobRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT.create(JobRequestFactory.class);
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);
JobRequest request = requestFactory.jobRequest();
JobProxy newJob = request.create(JobProxy.class);
requestFactory.jobRequest().findAllJobs().to(new Receiver<List<JobProxy>>(){
public void onSuccess(List<JobProxy> jobs)
{
    System.out.println("SIZE:"+jobs.size());
}
}).fire();
```

Finally my error is:

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator die
SEVERE: No RequestContext for operation Lk3VEjMsjGdUyVzlgtz$ggTrjMA=
```

I can't figure out why this happens...

Answer (score 0):

It would generally mean that the [ValidationTool](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation) (or annotation processor) didn't run with the latest version of your `JobRequestFactory`, particularly that you run it while either `JobRequest` didn't existed, `JobRequestFactory` had no method returning a `JobRequest`, or `findAllJobs` didn't exist or had a different signature (e.g. taking arguments).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, i had both hibernate-annotation and rf-apt as annotation processor, i kept only rf-apt but still the same. The snippet in the entry module posted above is executed at very first lines. I have cleaned project in eclipse, restarted sessions.. but still same.

Comment: How/when is ValidationTool run? How is you project launched/deployed? Is this in DevMode or prod mode? with server code in DevMode or deployed into another servlet container?

Comment: Project is launched over eclipse in devmode and not in another servlet. I don't do anything special with validationtool than have it on build path.

Comment: So you have [configured Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation#Eclipse) to run the annotation processor? Does the generated `JobRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder` class correctly references your `findAllJobs`, with the correct signature? (and what's its operation token? is it the same as the one reported in the error message?)